# WinDbg symbol proxy

Tags: iis, windbg

I want to set up such proxy, and have next to zero experience with IIS.
The most convenient is to use a 2012 64 bits server.

I have tried to follow various “how to”, but failed (They seems to target 2003 server).
I have also noticed that inside the  Windbg 6.3.9600  package, there is a symproxy folder without documentation, but in older versions there is a symhttp.doc. However, there is no indication of date or which version this is targeting.

Is there any “how to” or tutorial of setting up a symbol proxy on the current line of Windows 64 bits OS?

Comment: Sorry to ask but you're checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558846(v=vs.85).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmartin/archive/2011/01/09/setting-up-a-symproxy-on-windows-server-2008.aspx? The latter is for 2008 but I can't imagine it's that much different

Comment: @EdChum Thanks, the 2. Link was what I needed to get it working. However I had to set read access to “anyone” on the “SymStore” folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the 2. Link from EdChum I succeeded to set up the symbol proxy on a W7/64.
At first attempt it didn’t work, but using Wireshark I discovered that

```
HTTP    236 0x3967 (14695)  GET /symbols/index2.txt HTTP/1.1 
HTTP    1487    0x0839 (2105)   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized  (text/html)
```

After triple checking that “IIS Application Pools” user had access, I added **read** access to “**everyone**” using file explorer. 
Now everything works, both symbol added locally,
and fetched downstream form /msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.